# Why Swagger UI sends OPTIONS request method instead of correct one, once i access to it through spring Gateway?

Tags: swagger, spring-webflux, openapi, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm implementing open API 3.0 (swagger) in a webflux project. So i have a miscroservice (`port 8080`) made in spring webflux where I've added open API 3.0. I can access to it through `http://localhost:8080/client-service/swagger/swagger-ui.html` and everything work great!

I can also access to my micro service through a spring gateway (port 8989). So the url to get swagger home page via gateway is `http://localhost:8989/client-service/swagger/swagger-ui.html`. But the problem is when I try to execute any endpoint (post, get, delete, put) I get an error, and in the console of client-service I have the following message **HTTP OPTIONS** `"/v2/clients/12"` and not **HTTP GET** `"/v2/clients/12"`.
You have any idea of why it works when i access it directly via the url of the service where it is implemented and not via spring gateway?

Comment: It is making a preflight request to check for CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request